# Could not clone [repo URL] Make sure [HEAD] is a valid branch....etc

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

My first time working with a unity project. I have run into this error even after manually cloning the repo into the packages folder.

Thought it was a problem with submodules, but after manually loading those as well, I'm still getting this error. In Manifest.json the dependency/link is correct.

Any ideas? Sorry if my lingo is incorrect, and I'll be happy to provide additional info if necessary

I have manually cloned the repo and submodules

checked the dependencies in manifest.json

Comment: could you show your `Packages/manifest.json`